# Solving Recursive time function T(n) = T(n-127)+127/logn

Tags: algorithm

I have no idea for this time function..

T(n) = T(n-127) + 127/logn , T(n) = 1 for all n<=2

I expand it and gets :

T(n) = 127[1/log(127) + 1/log(2*127) + ... + 1/log(n)]

I need tight bound (Theta)

plz give me any hint

Comment: Suspicious duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321676/the-time-complexity-of-tn-tn-127-127-logn

Comment: lol seems that he is in the same course

Comment: Since this is homework, you need to cite this web site as a source of external assistance. To do otherwise would be academically dishonest.

Comment: Yes, i would. This homework also require us to put reference in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose it is `T(n) = T(n-c) + c/log(n)`. Now expand it (suppose `n = k * c` w.l.o.g.):

```
T(n) = c/log(n) + c/log(n-c) + c/log(n-2c) + ... + c/log(c)
```

Hence, it goes `k` times and final result is `T(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} c/log(n-i * c)`. As  `n = k * c`:

```
T(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} c/log((k- i) * c) = 
       \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} c/(log(k- i) + log(c))
```

`c = 1` maximizes the `T(n)` without chaning the asymptotic value of it. Hence, we need to find the asymptotic value of
[image]
. By @user58697, we have the following upper bound:

[image]

However, for the `\Theta` bound, we need a lower bound as well.

[image]

Hence,
[image]. Therefore,
[image]
.

Comment: Looks like you've stopped too early.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the OmG answer: if you reverse the order of summation,

```
T(n) = sum c/log(i*c)
```

it is easy to see that the sum is approximated by the integral of `dx/log(x)`, which is a well known [Logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). Its [asymptotic behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion) is `O(x/log(x))`.